# Unable to update a URL using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am developing a Google Analytics plugin and am facing problem with pagination which is based on [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). The data will be requested for every next and previous link as it is the pagination. **(I solved it; it was a typing mistake.)**

I am not able to get the next and previousLink updated correctly.

I have attached the screenshot and codes below.

**The jQuery code to request the next and previousLink for next and previous link clicks**:

```
jQuery('document').ready(function(){
    jQuery('.next-page,.prev-page').click(
        function( event ){
            event.preventDefault();

            url = jQuery(this).attr('href');
            console.log( url );
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: url,
                context: document.body
            }).done(function( data ){
                console.log(data.previousLink);
                console.log(data.nextLink);// https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:85914642&dimensions=ga:pagePath,ga:date&metrics=ga:pageviews,ga:uniquePageviews,ga:sessionDuration,ga:bounceRate,ga:exits&sort=ga:pageViews&filters=ga:pageViews%3C%3D10&start-date=7daysAgo&end-date=today&start-index=1&max-results=10
                if( data.previousLink != 'undefined' && accessToken != 'undefined' ){
                   // jQuery('.prev-page').prop("href", data.previousLink + '&access_token=' + accessToken );
                    jQuery('.prev-page').attr("href", data.previousLink + '&access_token=' + accessToken );//for first nextlink click and then previous link click http://localhost/analytica-test/wp-admin/undefined&access_token=ya29.RwLlLWsZlGzURfJiOYwkefk_Kpu0XIpKj0XoPHi5_n8nbSdmguInQgLRxXo3Ld0YjdvXeQ
                    //jQuery('.prev-page').href =  data.previousLink + '&access_token=' + accessToken ;
                }
                if( data.nextlink != 'undefined' && accessToken != 'undefined' ){
                   // jQuery('.next-page').prop("href", data.nextLink + '&access_token=' + accessToken );//after first time nextlink is clicked http://localhost/analytica-test/wp-admin/undefined&access_token=ya29.RwJ0guP0f2kr17Jyz8Dqcg0sM7RN4IQpyAehMpniRh8tspbNaIjcUvb2tzPI9ZD8zdG5DQ
                    jQuery('.next-page').attr("href", data.nextLink + '&access_token=' + accessToken );// after first time nextlink is clicked http://localhost/analytica-test/wp-admin/undefined&access_token=ya29.RwLlLWsZlGzURfJiOYwkefk_Kpu0XIpKj0XoPHi5_n8nbSdmguInQgLRxXo3Ld0YjdvXeQ
                    //jQuery('.next-page').href =  data.nextLink + '&access_token=' + accessToken ;
                }
        });
    });
});
```

**HTML when page is loaded fresh**

```
**<div class="tablenav-pages"><span class="displaying-num">445 items</span>
<span class="pagination-links"><span class="tablenav-pages-navspan" aria-hidden="true">«</span>
<a class="prev-page" href="&amp;access_token=ya29.RwIyTJjW7Bi0l-SLAQozJF6TT_-ynCOX1dzvMyOEdafY3NNp1CcO18codDhmoJYiucVCfw"><span class="screen-reader-text">Previous page</span><span class="tablenav-pages-navspan" aria-hidden="true">‹</span></a>
<span class="screen-reader-text">Current Page</span><span id="table-paging" class="paging-input">1 of <span class="total-pages">45</span></span>
<a class="next-page" href="https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:85914642&amp;dimensions=ga:pagePath,ga:date&amp;metrics=ga:pageviews,ga:uniquePageviews,ga:sessionDuration,ga:bounceRate,ga:exits&amp;sort=ga:pageViews&amp;filters=ga:pageViews%3C%3D10&amp;start-date=7daysAgo&amp;end-date=today&amp;start-index=11&amp;max-results=10&amp;access_token=ya29.RwIyTJjW7Bi0l-SLAQozJF6TT_-ynCOX1dzvMyOEdafY3NNp1CcO18codDhmoJYiucVCfw"><span class="screen-reader-text">Next page</span><span class="tablenav-pages-navspan" aria-hidden="true">›</span></a>
<span class="tablenav-pages-navspan" aria-hidden="true">»</span></span></div>**
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is a typo error. `data.nextlink` is not the one coming in the feed. It is `data.nextLink` (CAPS 'L' ).

Comment: in which line you have noticed small 'l' in data.nextLink ?

Comment: wherever you referred data.nextlink, small 'l' is used. It should be capital. (e-g)
                        jQuery('.next-page').prop("href", data.nextlink + '&access_token=' + accessToken );

Comment: You are right, the problems were some spelling mistakes . thank you.